# How to compare two JSON string in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have two long JSON string and what I need is compare these strings and find if they are equals or not, if it's not equal I can get list1 which contains (JSON1-JSON2) and list2 contains (JSON2-JSON1)

I find this ( https://github.com/google/dart-json_diff ) but it's very annoying and I don't know how to use this

I mean something like this

```
        final json1 = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        final json2 = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

        var list1= compare(json1,json2);
        var list2= compare(json2,json1);

    List<dynamic> compare (List<dynamic> json1,List<dynamic> json1){
    .
    .
    code?
    .
    .
    return results;
    }
/////////////////
    json1=[
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
        "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
      },
    ]
/////////////////
    json2=[
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat ",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi "
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ea molestias quasi",
        "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 4,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi "
      },
    ]
//////////
list1=[
          {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 4,
            "title": "qui est esse",
            "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi "
          },
       ]
```

thank u

Comment: What does "compare" mean?

Comment: I need this compare function to get the result in a list

Comment: Still you didnt explain what does it mean "to compare" to you

Comment: Give an example of what `json1` and `json2` contains and want you want `results` to contain.

Comment: I edited my question with an example. is it clear now?

Comment: what does comparing mean here? I mean why `list1` is like that after  comparison?

Comment: compare here is a function which retrieves the difference between two JSON strings. I mean any item in json2 and not in json1 will be in list1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok  this code working for me:

```
Future<String> _loadTestDataAssetsCloud() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/testDataCloud.json');
}

Future<String> _loadTestDataAssetsUrl() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/testDataUrl.json');
}

Future testData() async {
  var jsonUrl = await _loadTestDataAssetsUrl();
  Map decodedUrl = jsonDecode(jsonUrl);
  List<dynamic> individualsUrl = (((decodedUrl['CONSOLIDATED_LIST']
      as Map)['INDIVIDUALS'] as Map)['INDIVIDUAL']);

  var jsonCloud = await _loadTestDataAssetsCloud();
  Map decodedCloud = jsonDecode(jsonCloud);
  List<dynamic> individualsCloud = (((decodedCloud['CONSOLIDATED_LIST']
      as Map)['INDIVIDUALS'] as Map)['INDIVIDUAL']);

  List<dynamic> newList = [];

  List<dynamic> delList = [];


  individualsUrl.forEach((itemUrl) {
    bool a = true;

    individualsCloud.forEach((itemCloud) {
      if (itemUrl['REFERENCE_NUMBER'] == itemCloud['REFERENCE_NUMBER']) {
        a = false;
      }
    });
    if (a == true) {
      newList.add(itemUrl);
    }
  });
  print('newList');
//  print(newList);
  print(newList.length);
  newList.forEach((f){
    print(f['REFERENCE_NUMBER']);
  });


  individualsCloud.forEach((itemCloud) {
    bool d = true;

    individualsUrl.forEach((itemUrl) {
      if (itemCloud['REFERENCE_NUMBER'] == itemUrl['REFERENCE_NUMBER']) {
        d = false;
      }
    });
    if (d == true) {
      delList.add(itemCloud);
    }
  });
  print('delList');
//  print(delList);
  print(delList.length);
  delList.forEach((f){
    print(f['REFERENCE_NUMBER']);
  });

}
```